# ¿Como puedo mandar a llamar el id de otra tabla para realizar un registro en otra tabla?

Tags: sql, php7

Estoy trabajando con php lo que pasa es de que quiero hacer el registro de documentos en un usuario ya registrado en una tabla llamada empleados y lo que quiero es traer el id de ese usuario para hacer su registro en otra pero a la hora de hacer el registro me lo permite, pero no me registra el id que quiero en el campo id_usuario de otra tabla. Les agradecería su apoyo.

```
if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
    **$empleados = intval($_GET['id']);** //Esta es la variable que creo yo me manda a llamar el id de mi tabla de empleados
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $fecha = date("j/m/Y");
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $tamano = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $respo = $_POST['responsable'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "archivos/" . $nombre;
    if ($nombre !="" && !empty($_POST['para'])) {
    if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
            $para= $_POST['para'];
            $titulo= $_POST['titulo'];
            $descri= $_POST['descripcion'];
            $db=new Conect_MySql();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_documentos(para,titulo,version,fecha,descripcion,tipo,responsable,archivo,**id_usuario**) VALUES('".$para."','".$titulo."','0.0','".$fecha."','".$descri."','".$tipo."','".$respo."','".$nombre."',**'".$empleados."'**)";
            $query = $db->execute($sql);
            if($query){
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Se guardo correctamente.\");</script>";  
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Hubo un error, intente nuevamente.\");</script>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, por que ".$empleados." esta utilizando comillas dobles a la hora de insertar el campo ? prueba con quitar estas comillas dobles

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando sesiones puedes recuperar el id con $_SESSION y almacenar el dato en una variable, si tu llave primaria es id pones ['id'] o ['id_usuario'], según sea el caso:

```
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Ejemplo:

```
$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$fecha = date("j/m/Y");
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
```